# Prevent uTorrent from downloading when disk quota is reached?

Tags: windows-xp, ntfs, bittorrent, utorrent, quota

The disk quota management in Windows XP is working with uTorrent but not in the ideal way: It notifies me that the download will not be saved because disk quota is full **but only upon uTorrent exit**.

So this means that if I don't exit uTorrent, it continues to download although the download will not be saved upon exit. Ideally I like it to tell me on uTorrent startup that disk is full and not on exit.

Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: Unless you want to implement code yourself unlikely.